# How to get video pixel location from screen pixel location?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

Wall of Text so I tried breaking it up into sections to make it better sorry in advance

## The problem

I have some video files that I am reading with ffmpeg to get the colors at specific pixels, and all seems well, but I just ran into a problem with finding the right pixel to input. I realized (or mistakingly believe) that the pixel location (x,y) on the screen will be different than the local pixel location so to speak of the video (ie. If I want to get pixel 50,0 of the video that will be different than my screen's pixel 50,0 because the resolutions don't match). I was trying to think of a way to convert my screen's pixel location into the "local pixel location", and I have two ideas but I am not sure if any of them is any good. Note I am currently using cmd+shift+4 on macos to get the screen coordinates and **the video is playing fullscreen like in the screenshot below**.

## Ideas

1. [image] If I manually measure and account for this vertical offset, would it effectively convert the screen coordinate into the "local" one?
2. If I instead adjust my `SwsContext` to put the destination height and width as that of my screen, will it effectively replace the need to convert screen coordinates to the video coordinates?

## Problems with the Ideas

The problems I see with the first solution are that I am assuming there is no hidden horizontal offset (or conversely that all of the width of the video is actually renderable on the screen). Additionally, this solution would only get an approximate result as I would need to manually measure the offsets, screen width, and screen height using the method I currently am using to get the screen coordinates.

With the second solution, aside from the question of if it will even work, the problem becomes that I can no longer measure what the screen coordinates I want are because I can't seem to get rid of those black bars in VLC.

## Some Testing I did

Given that if the black bars are part of the video itself, my entire problem would be fixed (maybe?) I tried seeing if the black bars were part of the video, and when I looked at the frame data's first pixel, it was black. The problem then is that if the black bars are entirely part of the video, then why are the colors I get for some pixels slightly off (I am checking with ColorSync Utility). These colors aren't just slightly off as in wrong but it seems more that they belong to a slightly offset region of the video.

However, this may be somewhat explained if ffmpeg reads right to left. When I put the top left corner of the video into the program and looked again at the pixel data in the frame for that location (location again was calculated by assuming the video location would be the same as the screen location) instead of getting white, I got a bluish color much like the glove in the top right corner.

## The Watered Down Code

```
    struct SwsContext *rescaler = NULL;
    rescaler = sws_getContext(codec_context->width, codec_context->height, codec_context->pix_fmt, codec_context->width, codec_context->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB0, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, 0);

// Get Packets (containers for frames but not guaranteed to have a full frame) and Frames
    while (av_read_frame(avformatcontext, packet) >= 0)
    {
        
        // determine if packet is video packet
        if (packet->stream_index != video_index)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        // send packet to decoder
        if (avcodec_send_packet(codec_context, packet) < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to decode packet");
        }
        
        // get frame from decoder
        int response = avcodec_receive_frame(codec_context, frame);
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (response < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to get frame");
        }
        
        // convert frame to RGB0 colorspace 4 bytes per pixel 1 per channel
        response = sws_scale_frame(rescaler, scaled_frame, frame);
        if(response < 0){
            perror("Failed to change colorspace");
        }
        // get data and write it
        int pixel_number = y*(scaled_frame->linesize[0]/4)+x; // divide by four gets pixel linesize (4 byte per pixel)
        int byte_number = 4*(pixel_number-1); // position of pixel in array
        // start of debugging things
        int temp = scaled_frame->data[0][byte_number]; // R
        int one_after = scaled_frame->data[0][byte_number+1]; // G
        int two_after = scaled_frame->data[0][byte_number+2]; // B
        int als; // where i put the breakpoint
        // end of debugging things
    }
```

## In Summary

I have no idea what is happening.

I take the data for a pixel and compare it to what colorsync utility says should be there, but it is always slightly off as though the pixel I was actually reading was offset from what I thought I was reading. Therefore, I want to find a way to get the pixel location in a video given a screen coordinate when the video is in fullscreen, but I have no idea how to (aside from a few ideas that are probably bad at best).

Also does FFMPEG put the frame data right to left?

## A Video Better Showing My Problem

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSEErs2lC3A

Comment: Just a guess ... Is the video resolution less than the screen resolution? If so, you could set the resolution of the window that the video is displayed in to the same resolution as the video. This should eliminate the letterboxing that you're currently experiencing. You could tell `ffmpeg` to _not_ use full screen (or toggle the "maximize" button in the window control bar). Then, the utility you're using to mark the desired pixel should/must return the window coordinates and _not_ the screen coordinates.

Comment: Another [messy] way ... I believe the `ffmpeg` command can split the video into [_many_ ;-)] `.jpg` files (one frame per file). You could probably also do this yourself in your program (hopefully selecting just the frames of interest).

Comment: Yes, my video resolution is 1920 x 1080 and my screen (macbook m3 16'') is 3456 × 2234. Just to clarify, I am using VLC to display my video and am checking the "screen coordinates" with that. I am then taking this and plugging it into my program. I'd rather not make a renderer, is there any way I can do this resolution setting with VLC?

Comment: I wish I could choose frames of interest, but I am trying to find the oscillation of colors of that little chemistry experiment in the screenshot, so I can't really do that :(. Theoretically, I could say that no color change is likely to happen within intervals of x number of frames, but I kind of already said I would get super high accuracy (whatever the framerate gets me) to my teacher so kinda dug myself into a hole there

Comment: Well, you've _already_ got the makings of a renderer because you're using `av_read_frame` ;-) From that, you can get a pointer to the frame buffer for that frame. As to the oscillation, how are you detecting it? Are you just finding it visually as the video flies by? Or, could you make copies of the frame buffers, and programmatically look for the oscillation by watching how given pixels change frame-to-frame (or whatever more complex algorithm you need (e.g. convolution kernel, etc.)? I use `vlc` a lot for video display but I've never used it to select pixels.

Comment: But, even with `vlc`, it _needn't_ display the video in full screen mode. You can toggle "maximize" or, IIRC, you can invoke it with a command line option to display the video in a window where the window coordinates are one-to-one with the video's coordinates.

Comment: `vlc` has an A-B mode. Click on the `AB` button once to mark the first frame (of interest). Click again to get the last frame. Then, `vlc` will loop those frames. Does that help? At all? :-) I have some years of experience in commercial high-res R/T video compression/decompression S/W development. So, I'd like to help if possible. But, I'm still struggling to understand how to characterize the distortion you're seeing, how to write a program that detects/corrects it frame-by-frame, etc.

Comment: I see 2 issues here, and I think they should be attacked separately.  #1 is rendering an image of one resolution to a compatible screen res. For that it's advisable to allocate a buffer and translate the image to that buffer, then send that buffer to the screen.  #2 is the mapping of buffer X,Y COORDs to screenX,Y COORDs. Fairly straightfwd with a buff_to_screen_coord(X,Y) func which returns new COORDs by adding/subtracting offsets to each input X,Y.  A complimenting screen_to_buff_coord(X,Y) is equally straightfwd.  Again, it gets easier if you separate the 2 problems into specific ops.

Comment: @CraigEstey I am getting oscillations by just extracting the color of a certain pre-specified pixel and seeing how long it takes for that color to return to the value after it starts changing. I don't think it's looping that's needed, and quite frankly, I don't know how to render stuff on the screen with MacOS, and I would rather not do it when I just need to measure one pixel's change. I will upload a video to demonstrate my distortion (I think I'm not explaining it properly) and all the steps I am doing.

Comment: Sorry it took a lot more than a while to upload to youtube here it is: https://youtu.be/NSEErs2lC3A. EDIT: Nevermind the quality is garbage, it is still processing on youtube's end